# If Micheal Burry created the Credit Default Swap on mortgage bonds, how did the CDO managers find enough CDS to fill their synthetic CDO's?

Tags: cdo, speculation

In the book [The Big Short](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B006VAGFFW), the author mentions that Michel Burry came up with the idea of creating CDS on mortgage bonds because he assumed the market was not sustainable due to too many subprime loans.

Later the concept of a CDO is mentioned. Which basically means a bond of mortgage bonds with different risk levels. They also mention synthetic CDO's, which are supposedly CDS (bets against) the regular CDO's, because they had trouble finding new mortgage loan creditors, using speculators as pseudo homeloan creditors.

So my question is, did the CDO Manager take over the idea of a mortgage CDS from Micheal Burry? Also who were counterparty of the CDS, the one who paid the premiums?

The book makes it clear only a handful of funds new of the impending catastrophe, who were all the people they needed to create enough synthetic CDO's to satisfy the market. They mention that the ratio of real creditors to speculators in the CDO space was 50 to 1. Wouldn't they need an absolutely mindboggling amount of speculators to make that happen?

Comment: "who were counterparty of the CDS, the one who paid the premiums?" Burry et al. were paying the premiums. It was alleged that some investment banks created synthetic CDOs precisely because people such as those you mention wanted to pay premium on CDS they knew would trigger, and that this was not adequately disclosed to the buyers of CDO tranches on the other side. https://www.sec.gov/news/press/2010/2010-59.htm

Comment: Many investors knew of the impending catastrophe, the issue was timing the crash. Even the CDS underwriters knew. But since their yearly bonuses would most likely payout before the crash, they still took bad bets because they would personally profit. "The market can stay irrational longer than you can stay liquid."